# @Html.Action is not calling the action inside the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am newbie in MVC.

In Razor I need to call a method inside a controller but its not working for me.

My Razor code is as below:

```
@helper SubmitCommnet()
{
    @Html.Action("Post2", "PostShow", new { id = 1111 });

}
```

and my Controller is as follow:

```
public class PostShowController : SurfaceController
{      
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public ActionResult Post2(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it not calling the Post2 method?

Comment: You are creating a helper right, this might be a dumb question, but are you using the helper in your view?

Comment: what is use of `@helper SubmitCommnet()`?

Comment: going along with what the others have said,  if you are just trying to redirect you can remove the @helper part and the link should then work for you

Comment: Show more code, where is SubmitComment called from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Razor`, you have to use a `Html.ActionLink` to do this, which generates a hyperlink tag from html, or use the hyperlink tag directly, for sample:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Post", // <-- Text for UI 
                "Post2",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "PostShow",  // <-- Controller Name.
                new { id = 1111 }, // <-- Route arguments.
                null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none. You need this value
                      //     otherwise you call the WRONG method ...
                      //     (refer to comments, below).
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Html.ActionLink` like you would `Url.Action`. Remember you need to specify the link text, too. Something tells me you want the following method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

<sup>[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)</sup>

Then you can call it using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "Post2", "PostShow", new { id = 1111 }, null)
```

Unfortunately if you need to provide the action, controller & route arguments, you need the prototype with `htmlAttributes` (however, you can simply pass `null`).

Comment: You've confused Action with ActionLink.  Html.Action does not render a link, it calls a Controller action and returns a partial.

Comment: @AaronLS: Typod and fixed it just as you commented. Apprently I'm sleeping today. (Good catch though, ty.)